# bindParam PDO PHP

Tags: php, pdo

I am having a problem with binding param or value, does anybody knows what wrong?
If i change ? to area it works :-$

```
$item = 'area';
$query = dbConnectionPDO::getConnect()->prepare( ' SELECT * FROM  ? ' );
$query->bindParam(1, $item, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();

while($resultId = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    ////
}
```

Is this a good solution? It works!

```
$select = 'select * from ' . $item . ' left join ' . $TableName . ' ';

$query = dbConnectionPDO::getConnect()->prepare("$select ON :three = :four");
$query->bindValue(':three', $three, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindValue(':four', $four, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();

while($resultId = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    ////
}
```

Comment: You're trying to bind a table name, not a parameter. I'm not sure you can actually do that.

Comment: Why would you parametrize the table to select from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to bind a table name, not a parameter. I'm not sure you can actually do that.

[bindParam](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) works by binding question-mark holders *or* named **parmeters**, not a table name.

```php
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories
    FROM fruit
    WHERE calories < ? AND colour = ?');
$sth->bindParam(1, $calories, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindParam(2, $colour, PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
$sth->execute();
```

If you're just looking into placeholder "replacement" you can just use sprintf, but be careful since if you'll be doing anything fishy or stupid (like accepting the table name from an external source), it might be leaky.

For example:

```php
$theQ = "SELECT * FROM `%s` LEFT JOIN `%s` ON `%s` = `%s`";
$runQ = sprintf($theQ, 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four');
```

Comment: @All, ahaa, thats the problem, but is there any solution. In the end i want this   $query = dbConnectionPDO::getConnect()->prepare("SELECT * FROM  :item LEFT JOIN :TableName ON :tree = :four");

Comment: You could just sprintf the table name, but be careful as it might be leaky if you're doing something fishy :)

$myQuery = "SELECT * FROM `%s`";
mysql_query(sprintf($myQuery, "myTable"));

Comment: Edited with an example of simple argument placeholding.

Comment: Yup, thats definitely OK. Just simple concatenation.

Comment: See above by the question :-)

Comment: whats concatenation, sorry iam new :-$

Comment: Concatenation is when you connect two strings with the `.` sign, like you did in your query. By the way you could also add the :three = :four to the same string like this : http://pastebin.com/GrEBuSsd

Comment: Ok, thnks. Do i need mysql_real_string_escape for sql injection?

Comment: You should use it on the values, not the entire query.

Comment: for example on "my" mysql_real_escape_string($three) and mysql_real_escape_string($four)?

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide a valid SQL statement where only literals are parametrized. Even if the database driver is dumb enough to accept the query, you'll end up executing something like:

```
SELECT * FROM 'area'
```

... which is obviously not what you intended.

Answer (score 0):

You cant parametrize a table name, only parameters.